# Javascript function adds a space

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
var ii='"'+'c0'+thecid+'"';  
var newcommhtml = '<div id="c0'+thecid+'" class="cnew clearfix">';
newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<section class="c-content">';  
newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('+ii+').style.display = "none";" style="color:black;">x</a>';  
newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<p>'+nl2br(textval)+'</p> </section></div>';
```

Basically when some conditions met it adds a section to the page with some text. To this section (row number 4 in the code above) adds a x to the section. 
I would like to do so that when that x is clicked the section disappears.

When I run this code on a webpage it doesn't work. I checked the id of the getElementById(), there something weird happens: A space is added before the id of the element, I don't know where it came from.

I'm unable to solve the problem, does anybody know why this happens?

Pictures of the result:

- http://s8.postimg.org/xq9xsykyd/image.png
- http://s4.postimg.org/79q82e6i5/image.png

Comment: Have you tired using this `var ii='c0'+thecid;` instead of this `var ii='"'+'c0'+thecid+'"';`?

Comment: Just so you know, instead of using `newcommhtml = newcommhtml + ...` you can simply use the shorthand form `+=` - eg `newcommhtml += ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var ii = 'c0'+thecid;
var newcommhtml = '<div id="'+ii+'" class="cnew clearfix">';
newcommhtml += '<section class="c-content">';  
newcommhtml += '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(\''+ii+'\').style.display = \'none\';" style="color:black;">x</a>';  
newcommhtml += '<p>'+nl2br(textval)+'</p></section></div>';
```

So:

- Don't add quotes to the `ii` variable
- Use `ii` for the id instead of recalculating it
- In the `onclick` the double quotes around `none` were wrong
- You could use `+=` for extending the string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ii='c0'+thecid;  
var newcommhtml = '<div id="'+ii+'" class="cnew clearfix">';
newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<section class="c-content">';  
newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('+ii+').style.display = "none";" style="color:black;">x</a>';  
newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<p>'+nl2br(textval)+'</p> </section></div>';
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for the problem is the double quotes adding with id name like "c04".

Just remove double quotes from your first line `var ii='"'+'c0'+thecid+'"';`

Change it to - `var ii = 'c0'+ thecid;`

Comment: change this  'document.getElementById('+ii+')' to 'document.getElementById(ii);'. it will work now....